# Head bearing lock nut thread on a vintage english bicycle

Tags: handlebars

I want to replace the bent forks on my 1950s Humber bicycle (made by raleigh)with another thats too long between the head bearing and the fork crown and will be need to be cut and rethreaded.My question is what size dye  will I need to put back the thread on the shortened 25mm tube ?
The origonal forks are obsolete so buying new is not an option.

Comment: I would guess you'd match the thread you need to match.

Answer (score 1):

You really should measure it to be sure, using a thread pitch gauge and caliper, but if it's made by Raleigh in that era it's probably 1"x26tpi. The frame bore and original stem OD are probably standard dimensions (30.2mm and 22.2mm respectively), and if they are then you can just use a new standard ISO 1" headset along with a new fork that takes standard 1"x24tpi threads.

I've avoided doing this judiciously enough that I don't really know the practical details, but it's common to hear of attempts at extending threads by very much using common dies and a handle going pretty rough.

Basic 26x1-3/8" replacement forks are still available new. In the US, any shop can get you [this one.](http://www.jbi.bike/web/checking_product_description.php?part_number=27439) It will have the standard 24tpi threads, so if your headset is 26tpi it will need to be replaced.

Comment: Nathan,Thank you for that I knew it was 26 per inch but wasnt sure what to ask for .Humbers have spit duplex forks that are hard to find in 28" and work out expensive to buy online.